# Angular4 send sms using twilio

Tags: javascript, angular, twilio, twilio-api

Hello guys I am trying to send sms from client side using twilio
 here is what I am trying

```
url = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC5b593d9bfeedd9e/Messages.json';
    axios.post(url,{
      "To" : "+9134324738",
      "From" : "+14698",
      "Body" : "Fgrgajshdkajsdhrom axios"
    },{headers: { Authorization: 'Basic sdfsdfsdf=',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-url' }
  })
```

but I am getting 400 bad request response

here is what I am getting in response

```
{
    "code": 21603,
    "message": "A 'From' phone number is required.",
    "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21603",
    "status": 400
}
```

Please suggest some

Comment: try to enter valid phone number

Comment: @Stwosch tried but getting same issue. I have just enter random number in question

Comment: Try specifying a 10 digit phone number 1469867890 like following `"From" : "+1469867890 "`

Comment: I had the same issue nothing i tried worked .

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We do not recommend that you make requests to the Twilio API directly from your front end JavaScript application. To do so, you would need to store or retrieve your account SID and auth token in the client side somewhere. If you do this, then a malicious attacker could get access to your credentials and abuse your Twilio account.

Instead, we recommend you perform the API request on the server side and use your Angular app to make a request to your server to trigger the request.

Comment: While good advice in general, it doesn't really solve the OP's problem, I think, which is "why does this thing I tried not work?"

Comment: That may be the case, however I do not want the thing they are trying to work because it may get shipped and cause much bigger issues for them. Sure, on Stack Overflow we should try to answer the question, but in this case it could do the OP a lot of damage, so I provide this advice too.